# Пересказ речи в предложении

Tags: прямая-речь, цитирование

*На вопрос "Что ты делал вчера вечером?" ты ответил: "Гулял с собакой".*

Скажите, все ли здесь правильно?

Answer (score 2):

Существуют два варианта оформления подобных предложений:

Вариант 1.   **На вопрос "Что ты делал вчера вечером?" ты ответил: "Гулял с собакой".**

Вариант 2.   На вопрос: **"Что ты делал вчера вечером?" – ты ответил: "Гулял с собакой".**

В данном случае лучше использовать первый вариант (в связи с нераспространенностью авторской части предложения).

**Примеры из учебника:**

Папа читал что-то и на вопрос мой «Бывают ли синие зайцы?»,  не поднимая головы, отвечал: «Бывают, мой друг, бывают».   **Несогласованное определение: только кавычки.**

Папа читал что-то и на вопрос мой: «Бывают ли синие зайцы?» – не поднимая головы, отвечал: «Бывают, мой друг, бывают». **Обычное оформление прямой речи с двоеточием (тире после вопросительной прямой речи).**

Comment: По-моему, если в контексте нет намека на то, кто задал вопрос,  **нельзя** этот вопрос оформлять как прямую речь.

Comment: Это Л. Н, Толстой "Детство" (глава 11). Папа читал что-то и на вопрос мой: «Бывают ли синие зайцы?», не поднимая головы, отвечал: «Бывают, мой друг, бывают».  В приведенном предложении также присутствуют два лица: задающий и отвечающий.

Comment: У Толстого все правильно, там ясно, кто задал вопрос.  "Приведенное предложение" - это то, о котором спрашивает PersonaNonGrata? Где же там лицо, задающее вопрос? Там без контекста невозможно понять, кто задал вопрос.

Comment: Но кто-то же его задал, какая разница,  названо или не названо лицо, это конкретный человек,  который во второй  части  обозначен местоимением "ты".

Comment: Mестоимением "ты" обозначен отвечающий, a не задающий вопрос. А вопрос мог быть в анкете, например.

Comment: Это не анкета, и пожалуй,  мы немного отклонились от курса. Есть классическая форма записи прямой речи (двоеточие, кавычки и т.д.), эта форма применяется не только для прямой речи в дословном понимании, но и при цитировании,  причем может использоваться в безличных предложениях, например: В пословице говорится.... Там никаких лиц нет.  Мы говорим: цитата может быть оформлена как прямая речь или другими способами.  Поэтому не стоит в этих случаях искать реального автора  речи, он может отсутствовать. В нашем же случае реально разговаривают  "я и ты". Можно было сказать: На мой вопрос...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59986/discussion-between---and-sibylla).